# Why is video not autoplaying? Using Dreamweaver / HTML

Tags: html, autoplay

The videos on my site are not autoplaying, and I think I have my code entered correctly.
The video is inside a table. Could that be the reason it is not working?
Using DreamWeaver CS6 to code. Here is one example...

```
 <tr>
        <td colspan="3" align="center" valign="top"><video width="640" height="360" controls="controls" autoplay="autoplay" >
          <source src="Name-Redacted.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
        </video></td>
      </tr>
```

I have also tried entering just 'controls autoplay' instead of 'controls="controls" autoplay="autoplay", but that didn't work either.
Interesting note... I have 16 videos, each on a separate page, and 5 or 6 of them autoplay on Chrome, none of them on Firefox. Not sure what to make of that.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Browsers have been trying to curtail auto play

Comment: Not a fix but please note that the [<source>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/semantics.html#the-source-element) tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification.

Comment: Also note that `align` and `valign` have been [obsolete](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/obsolete.html#non-conforming-features) for decades.

Comment: Thanks for the heads-up @Rob. I am decades behind the curve. :) 
So what do I use instead of 'align' and 'valign'? Do I just type 'center' and 'top'?

Answer (score 0):

Many browsers have added some limitations for `autoplay` option on videos, so the problem isn't video being inside a table.

If you don't need the sound of the video, adding `muted` attribute would usually fix the problem on most browsers.

Even with JavaScript you wouldn't be able to hack around the problem, since it will throw a warning in developer console.

If you don't need the sound, rewrite your code as follows:

```
<tr>
    <td colspan="3" align="center" valign="top"><video width="640" height="360" controls autoplay muted >
      <source src="Name-Redacted.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
    </video></td>
  </tr>
```

Comment: Thanks, Kesetovic. I definitely need the sound, so I guess I am just going to have to live with no autoplay. :(